# How to resolve error of Update Rate Limits in Twitter in android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I have to integrate twitter in my application. I have integrated but I from yesterday I am getting error of Update Limit. Before it was working but now I am getting error of rate limit.

403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:---or----
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3-e574402b], statusCode=403, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}

Comment: I am also getting the same error.

Comment: which twitter jar files you are using...

Comment: twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter API update limits error 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536721/twitter-api-update-limits-error-403)

Answer (score 1):

There has been a [recent change to the Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239).  You can now **only** call it using HTTPS.

You should ensure that the URL you / your library is using starts with

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
```

(Notice the extra `s` after the `http`.)

Comment: Terence rightnow I am using twitter sample project where I have to make changes

Comment: Where did you get the code from? Search through it until you find the API string, then change it to https.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and upgrading to the latest version of twitter4j 3.0.5  fixed my issue.
Get the latest here http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download
I should mention that the version i was running was twitter4j 3.0.3. So by going to version 3.0.5 or 3.0.6 fixed the my issue.