# Twitter API update limits error 403

Tags: java, twitter

I am trying to retrieve data from twitter api with the twitter4j api. After some time retrievig data  I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - User has been suspended.
code - 63
```

I came to conclusion that the above error derive limits of the calls that the twitter api support. How is it possible to create intervals in order to wait until it could be possible to fetched data from twitter?

For example my code is the following:

```
            Long l = Long.parseLong(list.get(index));
            TwitterResponse response = twitter.getFollowersIDs(l);
            RateLimitStatus status = response.getRateLimitStatus();
            if (status.getRemaining() < 2) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("status.getSecondsUntilReset()");
                    Thread.sleep(status.getSecondsUntilReset());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
            User user = twitter.showUser((l));
            //statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(l);
            JSONObject features = new JSONObject();

            features.put("_id", l);
            score = kloutScore(l);
```

My new code contains a if statement which check if status.getRemaining() is close to zero then it waits for 15 minutes which is actually the limit duration. However I got problems with TwitterResponse response = twitter.getFollowerIDs(l); I am getting the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" 429:Returned in API v1.1 when a request cannot be served due to the application's rate limit having been exhausted for the resource. See Rate Limiting in API v1.1.(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)
message - Rate limit exceeded
```

Comment: My answer includes instructions on how yo can avoid exceeding the rate limits imposed by Twitter. However, the account you are using has already been suspended by Twitter. You need to use a different user (at least until the suspension of the user you are currently using has been lifted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each response you can call `getRateLimitStatus()` to get a `RateLimitStatus`. `RateLimitStats.getRemaining()` will tell you the remaining number of API requests available for that family of calls, if that reaches zero you could then call `RateLimitStatus.getSecondsUntilReset()`, and wait at least that long before making additional calls.

Information on Twitters rate limits can be found here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

Here is a basic example:

```
do {
    TwitterResponse response = twitter.getFollowersIDs(userId, cursor);
    RateLimitStatus status = response.getRateLimitStatus();
    if(status.getRemaining() == 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(status.getSecondsUntilReset() * 1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
} while(cursor > 0);
```

In the code you have now provided you are making 2 calls to Twitter, `showUser` and `getUserTimeLine`. You need to check the rate limit status after both of these calls (both `User` and `ResponseList` extend `TwitterResponse` and have the rate limit information). These calls belong to 2 different resource families (`users` and `statuses`), both of these methods are allowed to be called 180 times per rate limit window (15 minutes).

Comment: I am not using cursor. I had a list with ids and I fetched data from twitter from every single id.

Comment: I ve tried to calculate  TwitterResponse response = twitter.getFollowersIDs(Long.parseLong(list.get(index)));
                RateLimitStatus status = response.getRateLimitStatus(); 
However I get the same error, basically it couldnt calculate TwitterResponse.

Comment: The account you are using has already been suspended (likely because of exceeding the rate limits). You'll have to try using a different account until that suspension has been lifted.

Comment: Your original question did not include code so I just showed a simple example which I made up. I've edited my response to address the additional questions posed in your edit.

Comment: How can I use your do-while without using cursor?

Comment: You can ignore the do-while if you aren't using the cursor. In your code you are using `Thread.sleep(status.getSecondsUntilReset());` however `Thread.sleep` uses ms not s, it should be `Thread.sleep(status.getSecondsUntilReset() * 1000);` like in my example. Also you should check the rate limits status on the `showUser` call as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and upgrading to the latest version of twitter4j 3.0.5 fixed my issue. Get the latest here http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download I should mention that the version i was running was twitter4j 3.0.3. So by going to version 3.0.5 or 3.0.6 fixed the my issue.

Comment: You have posted duplicate answers which aren't allowed actually! Instead you should post a single answer and leave a comment with that link wherever necessary.