# Get user data by using Twitter Streaming API, Twitter Rest API

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I do some analysis on twitter users features like number of following , number of retweet, number of friend , etc 
I have all my information from Twitter Rest API 
But there is an Rate Limit Exceeded error occurred when I tried to retrieve all data 
can I have all these data  from Twitter Streaming API , if I can , how I can you it?
If not what Is the Solution?

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each response you can call getRateLimitStatus() to get a RateLimitStatus and if remaining calls is 0, sleep the thread till time limit is over.

```
do {
    TwitterResponse response = twitter.getFollowersIDs(userId, cursor);
    RateLimitStatus status = response.getRateLimitStatus();
    if(status.getRemaining() == 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(status.getSecondsUntilReset() * 1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
} while(cursor > 0);
```

[Twitter API update limits error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536721/twitter-api-update-limits-error-403)

Comment: Thanks for reply , I did this steps but it still give me the same error